# Change Apple Analytics download format from CSV to PDF

Tags: pdf

When I first started downloading Metrics reports, the download button gave me choices and I meant to click PDF, but accidentally clicked CSV format. Now it won't bring up the selection list, and I'm forced to download CSV reports. How can I switch it so I can download Metrics reports in PDF? Thanks.

Comment: Oh, and I'm using Firefox and have changed all those settings that I can.

Answer (score 2):

Readdle has a nice PDF converter that you can use in the meantime to convert it on your iPhone from csv to pdf.

https://readdle.com/products/pdfconverter